# Error setting text on TextView in Android

Tags: java, android, textview

I keep getting a null pointer error, but I can't figure out why. Is there something very obvious I'm missing?

```
final Dialog d = new Dialog(Start.this);
        // dialog.requestWindowFeature((int) Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        d.requestWindowFeature((int) android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        d.setContentView(R.layout.popuptwo);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        d.show();

        d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        TextView totaltxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totaltxt);
            totaltxt.setText("Test text");
```

If I remove `totaltxt.setText("Test text");` then the program doesn't crash. Ideas?

Comment: (but my guess is you need to call d.findViewById)

Comment: Are you sure to have totaltxt TextView in popuptwo Layout?

Comment: TextView totaltxt = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.totaltxt);

Answer (score 3):

The text view belongs to the dialog..so you should use the dialog's view..

```
TextView totaltxt = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.totaltxt);
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much. That does make sense now. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just do..`TextView totaltxt = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.totaltxt);
 totaltxt.setText("Test text");`

Answer (score 0):

Because it unable to get the view for dialog so,

Replace this line--

```
  TextView totaltxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totaltxt);
```

by this--

```
  TextView totaltxt = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.totaltxt);
```

here d is your dialog object.